# jQuery selector by Id not working

Tags: jquery, html, selector

Here is my issue:

I have a set of three accordion boxes managed by a jQuery script, as below:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-content').hide();
    jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-title:first').addClass('active').next().show();
    jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-title').click(function(){
        if( jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
            jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
        }else {
     jQuery(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); 
        }
        return false; // Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
   <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" style="text-align: center;" href="">Title1</a>
    <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
     <p>Some text</p>
    </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
   </div><!--end .accordion-section-->

   <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" style="text-align: center;" href="">Title2</a>
    <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
     <p>Some text.</p>
    </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
   </div><!--end .accordion-section-->

   <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" style="text-align: center;" href="">Title3</a>
    <div id="accordion-3" class="accordion-section-content">
     <p>Some text.</p>
    </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
   </div><!--end .accordion-section-->
  </div><!--end .accordion-->
```

As you can see the second jQuery initializes the first accordion box to be visible when the page is loaded, which works fine. But I would like to have the second one, the one in the middle, to be displayed instead. Therefore I tried to change

```
jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-title:first')
```

by

```
jQuery('#accordion-2')
jQuery('.accordion #accordion-2')
jQuery('.accordion').find('#accordion-2')
jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-title #accordion-2')
```

And various other possibilities I could find to select an element by Id (which I believe is appropriate in this case?), nothing does...

I do not understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-title:first')` selects `<a class="accordion-section-title" style="text-align: center;" href="">Title1</a>`

`jQuery('#accordion-2')` selects `<div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">`.

You need `jQuery('#accordion-2').prev()`

Comment: Damn, I'm tired... Thank you so much, can't believe I didn't see it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-title:eq(1)')
```

should do the trick. The `:eq(1)` will filter out the second DOM element in the 0-based list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your jQuery selector, it's with the .next();

Try this instead (tested it, it works):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-content').hide();
    jQuery('#accordion-2').addClass('active').show();
    jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-title').click(function(){
        if( jQuery(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {
            jQuery('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();
            jQuery(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();
        }else {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); 
        }
        return false; // Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
    });
});
```